# Register Tortoise signals in fast API

Tags: python, signals, fastapi, tortoise-orm

I just created a signal to generate a token when the user is created, I use tortoise.signals to generate it in a separate file, my project structure is like this

```bash
├── Makefile
├── README.md
├── core
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── authentication.py
│   ├── email.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── router.py
│   ├── schema.py
│   ├── signals.py
│   └── views.py
├── main.py
├── requirements.txt
├── static
└── templates
    └── verification.html
```

And here is my signal file

```py
# signals.py

from tortoise.signals import post_save
from tortoise import BaseDBAsyncClient
from typing import Type, List, Optional

from .models import UserModel, business_pydantic
from .email import send_email


@post_save(sender=UserModel)
async def create_business(
    sender: "Type[UserModel]",
    instance: UserModel,
    created: bool,
    using_db: Optional[BaseDBAsyncClient],
    update_fields: List[str],
) -> None:
    if created:
        business_objects: UserModel = await UserModel.create(
            business_name = instance.username, owner_id = instance
        )
        await business_pydantic.from_tortoise_orm(business_objects)
        
        # send email
        await send_email([instance.email], instance)
```

and I import the module in function `create_app`

```py
from dotenv import dotenv_values
from fastapi import FastAPI
from tortoise.contrib.fastapi import register_tortoise
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles

from .router import router


def create_app():
    app = FastAPI()
    
    # mount static files
    app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")
    import signals # <- import my signal file here
    register_tortoise(
        app=app,
        db_url="postgres://postgres:1234@localhost:5432/ecommerce_db",
        modules={"models": ["core.models"]},
        generate_schemas=True,
        add_exception_handlers=True,
    )
    # add routes
    app.include_router(router)

    return app
```

My problem is that the signal that I created in the `signals.py` file is not read/executed, how do I make the functions that I make executed properly if I make them in a separate file, is there a way to register so that the signal is read in fast API?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you importing your signals file anywhere? What does your signals file look like?

Comment: how to import it

Comment: `import .signals` or `import core.signals` or in your models file could be one way to do it, depending on your project setup